# Form Validation through Jquery: This not working with Jquery Latest version of CDN (Content Delivery Network)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This not working with Jquery Latest version of CDN (Content Delivery Network):

```html
Validating HTML forms is a very important aspect during form submission. jQuery helps in validating forms at client side. The following steps are required to validate a form.

Step 1: Create a Simple HTML Form
To create the form use the following code.
<h1>Fill out your information</h1>
<form id="regForm" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Your Full Name"/>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email ID"/>
  <input type="text" name="mobileno" id="mobileno" id="mobileno" placeholder="Mobile Number" maxlength="10"/>
  <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password"/>
  <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" value="" placeholder="RetypePassword"/>
  <button name="submit" type="button" id="btnvalidate">Click to Submit</button>
</form>
```

[This is the form view of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyAaU.png)

Step 2: Include the Latest jQuery Library
The latest jquery library can be downloaded from https://jquery.com/. Add the latest library to the head section of HTML page.

Step 3: Add a Function to Validate Form
Add the jquery function within the "" tags in the HTML form. Use the following code to validate the form.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

  //Find the values added in form using the id of each fields. The ".val()" function finds the value added in the form fields.
  var fullname = $('#fullname').val();
  var address = $('#address').val();
  var mobileno = $('#mobileno').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var indexat = email.indexOf("@"); //Index of "@" in the email field
  var indexdot = email.indexOf("."); //Index of "." in the email field
  var password = $('#password').val();
  var repassword = $('#repassword').val();
  
  //Function will execute when the button "Click to Submit" is clicked.
  $('#btnvalidate').click(function() {
   
    //Blank field validation of fullname, mobile no and address. The function will generate an alert message if "fullname" or "mobile no" or "address" field is blank  
    if(fullname == '')
    {
   alert('Please enter your Full Name');
   $('#fullname').focus(); //The focus function will move the cursor to "fullname" field
    }
    else if(address == '')
    {
   alert('Please enter your Address');
   $('#address').focus();
    }
    else if(mobileno == '')
    {
   alert('Please enter your Mobile Number');
   $('#address').focus();
    }
    
    //Validation of valid email address. The function will generate an alert message if "email" field is blank or incorrect
    else if(indexat < 1 || (indexdot-indexat) < 2)
    {
   alert('Please enter a valid Email Id');
   $('#email').focus();
    }
    
    //Validation of password. The function will generate an alert message if "password" field is not same as "retype password".
    else if(password == '' && password != repassword)
    {
   alert('Password and Retype password donot match');
   $('#repassword').focus();
    }
  });
  
</script>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Are you getting any error please describe us.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get all the text field values inside your click event.